# How to build linphone voip sdk for android?

Tags: android, linux, linphone

I am building the linphone voip sdk for android. I am following the readme file of the source.

In the 2nd step,

2) install yasm, nasm, curl, ant, rsync and the autotools: autoconf, automake, aclocal, libtoolize, pkgconfig
    On 64 bits linux systems you'll need the ia32-libs package
    With the latest Debian (multiarch), you need this:
        dpkg --add-architecture i386
        aptitude update
        aptitude install libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386

when I tried to install aclocal.I go t the following error. Can anyone please help me.

> irfan@irfancomputer:~$ sudo apt-get install aclocal
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   E: Unable to locate package aclocal

Also if anyone know the complete steps in detail to buld the project, please share here. Thank you.

Comment: run make command without installing aclocal. aclocal is not necessary.

Comment: irfan, have you compiled it? Please give the complete steps to compile Linphone android. Thank you